# How to get the archive post type/format in the loop?

Tags: archive-template

How do I find out if the archive is a post *format*, like 'gallery' (www.example.com/type/gallery/)?

I can use `is_archive()` and and `is_search()` for those.

Is there something like `is_type()` or `is_format()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `has_post_format` to check the if the post format equal to some format type.

From the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_format)

```
if ( has_post_format('gallery') ) {
    // Do something
 }
```

Or use `$format = get_post_format()` and then do some condition..

```
$format = get_post_format();
if ( $format == 'gallery' ) {
    // Do something
 }
```

If you want to use it outside the loop there is a problem with this method. because it check if the first post is in the format.

So its could return false positive if you are in category page when the first post has the post format too.

For outside the loop you can check for the `get_queried_object`

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
if($queried_object->taxonomy == 'post_format' && $queried_object->name == 'Gallery') {
    // Do something
}
```